# unsubscribe from observable when it emits a certain value

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

How can I unsubscribe from an observable when I receive a certain value ?

Like this :

```
 let tempSub: Subscription = this.observable$.subscribe(value => {
    if (value === 'somethingSpecific') {
      tempSub.unsubscribe(); 
      // doesn't work 
      //because when this is reached tempsub is undefined
    }
  });
```

Comment: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeWhile

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `takeWhile` operator

```
source.takeWhile(val => val === 'somethingSpecific');
```

or

```
this.observable$
.takeWhile(val => val === 'somethingSpecific')
.subscribe(value => {
 // .. do something
});
```

don't forget to import it

here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/btroncone/yakd4jgc/